# How to install CUDA 7.5?

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I installed gcc-4.8

Run the installer CUDA **[.run]**

And received the error:

```
Using more to view the EULA.
Error: unsupported compiler: 5.2.1. Use --override to override this check.
Missing recommended library: libGLU.so
Missing recommended library: libX11.so
Missing recommended library: libXi.so
Missing recommended library: libXmu.so

Error: cannot find Toolkit in /usr/local/cuda-7.5

===========
= Summary =
===========

Driver:   Not Selected
Toolkit:  Installation Failed. Using unsupported Compiler.
Samples:  Cannot find Toolkit in /usr/local/cuda-7.5
```

Comment: did you ever find an answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

I have/had this **exact** problem...except I wasn't missing all of the additional libraries you are.  I just downloaded the latest **gcc** compiler, and ran:

```
sudo sh your_cuda_run_file --override
```

And then I did a test with a tensor flow GPU tutorial and it ran perfectly.

---

However, this is my "hpc" desktop, where I don't keep anything important, and have a fresh install of ubuntu...so I can afford to install Cuda on an unsupported operating system (Ubuntu 15.10) and use an unsupported compiler (gcc 5.2.1).

The "correct" configuration is 15.04 (which I think you can still get on a bittorrent) and gcc 4.8 or 4.9.1 or something.

---

Anyways, nothing stupid can happen--the BIOS protects the hardware...and the software can be salvaged from safe mode. So yeah: override it.